# Spring Non-blocking Rest "Send and forget"

Tags: java, spring, rest, spring-mvc, asynchronous

I'm writing a non-blocking Spring Rest controller. My client should send a request and doesn't care for the response and doesn't need to wait.

This is my server code:

```
@RestController
@EnableAsync
public class testController {

@RequestMapping(value = "test", method = RequestMethod.GET)
public ResponseEntity<String> test() throws InterruptedException {
    timeConsumingMethod();
    System.out.println("I'm should be first");
    return new ResponseEntity<String>("the server is processing your request", HttpStatus.OK);
}

@Async
private void timeConsumingMethod() throws InterruptedException {
    Thread.sleep(1000*5);
    System.out.println("I'm should be second!");
}
```

However, When I call http://localhost:8181/test using(POSTMAN, Chrome, etc...)
I get the following on the server log:

**I'm should be second!**

**I'm should be first**

AND only after waiting 5 seconds my browser shows:

**the server is processing your request**

Is that the correct way for a "send and forget" Behavior?

Comment: `@Async` doesn't work for methods called on the same class. Nor does `@EnableAsync` work on a controller it should be on a `@Configuration` class.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

According to the doc page the [`@EnableAsync`](http://docs.spring.io/spring-framework/docs/current/javadoc-api/org/springframework/scheduling/annotation/EnableAsync.html) should be added on configuration class.

> Enables Spring's asynchronous method execution capability, similar to
>   functionality found in Spring's  XML namespace.
>
> To be used on @Configuration classes as follows, where MyAsyncBean is
>   a user-defined type with one or more methods annotated with either
>   Spring's @Async annotation, the EJB 3.1 @javax.ejb.Asynchronous
>   annotation, or any custom annotation specified via the annotation()
>   attribute.

Comment: @yuz I have same situation, but i build my controller and service in the right way. idk not works... bean https://pastebin.com/ZejaaUcg config https://pastebin.com/Dz6aFya4 service https://pastebin.com/wbRLrupd

Answer (score 0):

why don't you use this:
https://www.baeldung.com/spring-webclient-resttemplate

Webflux client seems to do the same. I was searching for a similar solution where 1 microservice calls multiple microservices async and this fits the model