# Spring boot async Interface-based controller not working

Tags: java, spring, spring-boot

I found this issue (or not an issue?) in Spring boot 2.0.*

```
@Async("someWorker")
public CompletableFuture<CreateAuthorResponse> authorPost(@RequestBody CreateAuthorRequest request)
        throws Exception {
    CompletableFuture<CreateAuthorResponse> future = new CompletableFuture<>();
    future.complete(authorDao.createAuthor(request.getFirstName(), request.getLastName()));
    return future;
}
```

And the interface is:

```
@RequestMapping(value = "/library/authors", method = RequestMethod.POST)
public CompletableFuture<CreateAuthorResponse> authorPost(@RequestBody CreateAuthorRequest request)
        throws Exception;
```

This controller can not be found in request mapping because of this following code in **AbstractHandlerMethodMapping.class**

```
protected void initHandlerMethods() {
        if (logger.isDebugEnabled()) {
            logger.debug("Looking for request mappings in application context: " + getApplicationContext());
        }
        String[] beanNames = (this.detectHandlerMethodsInAncestorContexts ?
                BeanFactoryUtils.beanNamesForTypeIncludingAncestors(obtainApplicationContext(), Object.class) :
                obtainApplicationContext().getBeanNamesForType(Object.class));

        for (String beanName : beanNames) {
            if (!beanName.startsWith(SCOPED_TARGET_NAME_PREFIX)) {
                Class<?> beanType = null;
                try {
                    beanType = obtainApplicationContext().getType(beanName);
                }
                catch (Throwable ex) {
                    // An unresolvable bean type, probably from a lazy bean - let's ignore it.
                    if (logger.isDebugEnabled()) {
                        logger.debug("Could not resolve target class for bean with name '" + beanName + "'", ex);
                    }
                }
                if (beanType != null && isHandler(beanType)) {
                    detectHandlerMethods(beanName);
                }
            }
        }
        handlerMethodsInitialized(getHandlerMethods());
    }
```

**beanType** is class com.sun.proxy.$Proxy but not CGLIB proxy, and **isHandler**  can't find any annotation from sun.proxy but work fine in CGLIB proxy.

**@EnableAsync(proxyTargetClass = true)** forcing every to CGLIB can fix this problem. Removing the interface can solve this too. But if only use **@EnableAsync** only, the controller can't be found by spring

```
@RestController
@Validated
public class LibraryControllerImpl {
    @Autowired
    AuthorDao authorDao;

    @Async("someWorker")
    @RequestMapping(value = "/library/authors", method = RequestMethod.POST)
    public CompletableFuture<CreateAuthorResponse> authorPost(@RequestBody CreateAuthorRequest request)
        throws Exception {
        CompletableFuture<CreateAuthorResponse> future = new CompletableFuture<>();
        future.complete(authorDao.createAuthor(request.getFirstName(), request.getLastName()));
    return future;
}
```

> 2018-06-27 16:35:02.376  INFO 150160 --- [           main] s.w.s.m.m.a.RequestMappingHandlerMapping : Mapped "{[/library/authors],methods=[POST],consumes=[application/json]}" onto public java.util.concurrent.CompletableFuture LibraryControllerImpl.authorPost(CreateAuthorRequest) throws java.lang.Exception

Comment: I am pretty sure `@Async` is not supposed to work together with `@RequestMapping` at least not, if the method is invoked remotely. HTTP and async requests simply don't go together.

Comment: Why make an async method async? The `CompletableFuture` already makes it async? Why on earth would you need to add another `@ASync`.

Comment: I would add to above comments only that code with completable future doesn't make sense. You are completing future before it is returned from controller. That is same as just returning plain `String`.

Comment: Sorry for the bad sample, I have fixed it already

Comment: @M.Deinum
I just need to control this method can be executed in the executor by `Async`

Comment: No you don't... The method is already async... You are asyncing an already async method... If you want to configure which executor is used for async web processing then configure that but this isn't the way to do it. Or just inject the executor and use `CompletableFuture.supplyAsync(task, your-executor)` instead of what you are doing now.

Comment: This do by Spring AOP. 
[link](https://docs.spring.io/spring-framework/docs/current/javadoc-api/org/springframework/aop/interceptor/AsyncExecutionAspectSupport.html#doSubmit-java.util.concurrent.Callable-org.springframework.core.task.AsyncTaskExecutor-java.lang.Class-)

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Is REST controller multithreaded?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/40794181/is-rest-controller-multithreaded)

Comment: @dpr No, it's totally different. The async task is working, but the controller vanish when I put `@Async` and separating interface.